# JQuery ajax doesn't work on dynamically added form

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of comments each with button vote inside.
When suer vote I call this function:

```
$(".vote").on("click", function (e) {...
```

But when I add new comment to the list I add it with this function:

```
$("#frmNewComment").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).attr("action");
            var formData = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (html) {
                    $(".comments-list").append(html);
                }
            });

        });
```

But it doesn't make AJAX request on it when vote.
Comment is submited to the server but no AJAX.
What should be done in this  sistuation?

Comment: Use delegation `$(document).on("click", ".vote", function() {});` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I guess the `id` `#frmNewComment` is being duplicated..

Comment: @gillesc that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    $("#frmNewComment").on("submit", function(event) {
```

To

```
    $("body").on("submit","#frmNewComment", function(event) {
```

It will work if you are change form element with ajax response

Use same for click event

```
    $("body").on("click",".vote", function (e) {...
```

Comment: Arguments of `on` are the wrong way around and this is not going to trigger when `.vote` is clicked.

Comment: Well now you have added the `.vote` part which wasn't there when first posted but the arguments are still wrong anyway. From jquery `on` documentation `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` the first argument is the event type, the second is the selector not the other way around.